# How to import value in GCCGO to perform something like go linker ldflags -X does in GC compiler

Tags: go, gcc, gccgo

Now, I have the bash code which can import the version value to the go source code in compiling time using the linker which is in the go tool. This code can run normally with GC.

> go build -ldflags "-X something:something" main.go

But I am testing my code in the machine whose architecture only supports gccgo instead of gc, and gccgo does not support -ldflags which is a linker tool in gc. Though gccgo has flag options which is -gccgoflags, I didn't see the linking flag I need.

I want to know whether there are any relative flags in gccgo or are there any alternative way to insert the value into source code?

I don't want to hard code this feature with bash.

Thanks.